# read write property of type record

Tags: delphi

Is their any drawback to declare a property of type record ?

```
  TMyObject = class(TObject)
  private
    FSomeRecord: TMyRecord;
  public
    property SomeRecord: TMyRecord read FSomeRecord write FSomeRecord;
  end;
```

How the instruction `Myobject.SomeRecord.xxx := yyy` will work under the hood (I think this can not work actually) ?

If it's can not work, how to do with record property? is it simply better to avoid it and declare TMyobject like below?

```
  TMyObject = class(TObject)
  public
    SomeRecord: TMyRecord;
  end;
```

Comment: Using of Record type properties is useful only when you need the ability to read or write the value of the entire record at once and not accessing individual fields of the record. For instance when you are trying to assign values of the separate record to your objects record using one command or vice versa. Could be useful for copying records between different objects for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that `Myobject.SomeRecord.xxx := yyy` will not work the way you want.  It will invoke the property getter, returning a *copy* of the record, and then you would be updating the `xxx` field of the copy, not the original.  Essentially, the generated code would act like this:

```
var tmp: TMyRecord;
tmp = Myobject.FSomeRecord;
tmp.xxx := yyy;
```

Unless you need RTTI for the property, there is no good reason to declare a read+write property that simply accesses a field directly.  Just expose public access to the field instead.

Comment: Thanks remy :) I just updated a little the question asking also in this way how to do with record? better to avoid them in property ?

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: I'm not sure for older Delphi versions but in Delphi 10.3 calling `Myobject.SomeRecord.xxx := yyy` will return `E2064 Left side cannot be assigned to` compiler error because compiler expect that you will provide another matching record type to either read or write values to.

Comment: @SilverWarior that is because modern versions are smart enough to know that the code is writing to a temporary that will have no effect. Old versions did not warn on that.

Comment: Define "Old" :-). I remember seeing this years ago (XE5 or thereabouts). I believe it was with a function returning a Record, but may remember wrong...

Answer (score 1):

One way to circumvent this is to declare the property as a POINTER to the record (if you only need access to the fields/methods *within* the record):

```
TYPE
  TMyRecord = RECORD
                Field1  : INTEGER;
              END;
  PMyRecord = ^TMyRecord;

TYPE
  TMyClass  = CLASS
          PRIVATE
            FMyRecord   : TMyRecord;
            FUNCTION    GetRec : PMyRecord;
          PUBLIC
            PROPERTY    MyRec : PMyRecord Read GetRec;
          END;

{ TMyClass }

FUNCTION TMyClass.GetRec : PMyRecord;
  BEGIN
    Result:=@FMyRecord
  END;

.
.
.
VAR
  MC    : TMyClass;
.
.
.
MC.MyRec.Field1:=12
.
.
.
```

Due to the "Extended syntax", you can short-circuit the normal syntax of

```
MC.MyRec^.Field1:=12
```

to

```
MC.MyRec.Field1:=12
```

but not the following use:

```
VAR NewRec : TMyRecord := MC.MyRec;
```

which would have to be coded as

```
VAR NewRec : TMyRecord := MC.MyRec^;
```

unless you introduce a RECORD HELPER for the PMyRecord that implements an implicit cast to TMyRecord:

```
TYPE
  PMyRecHelper  = RECORD HELPER FOR PMyRecord
                    CLASS OPERATOR Implicit(P : PMyRecord) : TMyRecord;
                  END;

{ PMyRecHelper }

CLASS OPERATOR PMyRecHelper.Implicit(P : PMyRecord) : TMyRecord;
  BEGIN
    Result:=P^
  END;
```

Unfortunately, the above code, while it compiles, doesn't work. Delphi does not allow operator overloaders in record helpers...

So until this last item is implemented, you only have a semi-working implementation...